# How to get lable name in dynamically?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_diplay_1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Margin="155,78,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="103.5" GotFocus="txt_diplay_1_GotFocus" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_diplay_2" Height="42" Margin="297,78,239.5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" GotFocus="txt_diplay_2_GotFocus" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_a" Content="A" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="155,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73" Click="btn_a_Click" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_b" Content="B" Height="40" Margin="237,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btn_b_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="73" />
    <Button x:Name="btn_c"  Height="40" Margin="0,147,239.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="73" Click="btn_c_Click" >
        <Grid Height="30.833" Width="61.5">
            <Label x:Name="lbl_1" Content="1" Margin="22.498,6.5,19.501,2.166"/>
            <Label x:Name="lbl_2" Content="!" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,-4.422,0,13.088" Width="19.501"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

The design will be like this

[image: Result]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Control TexboxDetails = null;      
    Control ButtonDetails;             
    Button BehaveButton;     

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

private void btn_a_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonDetails = (Control)sender;
        all_in_one();
    }

    private void btn_b_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonDetails = (Control)sender;

        all_in_one();
    }

    private void btn_c_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void txt_diplay_1_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TexboxDetails = (Control)sender;
    }

    private void txt_diplay_2_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TexboxDetails = (Control)sender;
    }

    public void all_in_one()
    {
        BehaveButton = ButtonDetails as Button;
        if (TexboxDetails != null)
        {
            TextBox BehaveTextbox = TexboxDetails as TextBox;
            var caret_index = BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex;
            BehaveTextbox.Text = BehaveTextbox.Text.Insert(caret_index, BehaveButton.Content.ToString());
            BehaveTextbox.Focus();
            BehaveTextbox.CaretIndex = caret_index + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

With above code i can get Button name dynamically when i click that button.
In above figure one button(btn_c) has two labels. now i want get that separate labels name dynamcially when i click button(btn_c).

Answer (score 1):

You can get them like this (inside the *btn_c* click handler):

```
var btn_c = (Button)sender;
Grid grid = (Grid)btn_c.Content;
Label label1 = (Label)grid.Children[0];
string name1 = label1.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your whole design could really use some rework.  Take a look at this code: (notice the reduced number of event handlers; you'll need to modify the XAML to use these)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TextBox LastFocusedTextBox;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InsertButtonContent((Button)sender);
    }

    private void txt_diplay_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LastFocusedTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    }

    public void InsertButtonContent(Button button)
    {
        if (LastFocusedTextBox != null)
        {
            string buttonContentString = button.Content as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(buttonContentString))
            {
                var grid = button.Content as Grid;
                if (grid != null)
                    buttonContentString = string.Join("", grid.Children.OfType<ContentControl>().Select(x => x.Content));
            }
            var caret_index = LastFocusedTextBox.CaretIndex;
            LastFocusedTextBox.Text = LastFocusedTextBox.Text.Insert(caret_index, buttonContentString);
            LastFocusedTextBox.Focus();
            LastFocusedTextBox.CaretIndex = caret_index + buttonContentString.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the `Button` are passed to the method instead of being stored in a field.  Also, unnecessary fields, both in the class and local to the `all_in_one()` method were removed.  To get the contents of the labels in the Grid (e.g. `"1!"` - I assume this is what you were after, since nothing else could go into a simple string field, and also match the general pattern of your first two buttons), we simply select their contents and join them into a single string, after checking if the content was a string or a Grid.

Comment: Tell me clearly, it seems to right answer but i can't understand. i have to get labels name when i click the btn_c.

Comment: Please place your code with my code then only i can understand.